# Why isn't zxing playing nicely with ant/java8 and the pom.xml?

Tags: java, ant, zxing

I changed a pom.xml entry to zxing to 3.3.0

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
      <artifactId>zxing-parent</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

and now I'm getting this:

```
[artifact:dependencies] Unable to resolve artifact: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core:jar': Invalid JDK version in profile 'java8-and-higher': Unbounded range: [1.8, for project com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core
[artifact:dependencies]   com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core:jar:1.3.1
```

From what I can find this indicates that something is wrong with the pom file for zxing related to the required versions of java (which I'm using java 8)?

The code compiles fine using Maven and Eclipse, but this error occurs when attempting to run a separate ant process.

```
<artifact:dependencies filesetId="dependency.fileset">
    <artifact:pom file="${basedir}/pom.xml"/>
</artifact:dependencies>
```

The ant task works just fine if I use zxing 2.2 in the pom but then of course my code does not.
Is this a bug in zwing 3.3.0 or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the problem is the `pom` of `jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core:jar:1.3.1`.

Maven has a problem with the following lines

```
<profile>
  <id>java8-and-higher</id>
  <activation>
    <jdk>[1.8,</jdk>
  </activation>
 ...
```

For a ugly fix you can open the `pom` in your local repository and change the activation value to

```
<profile>
  <id>java8-and-higher</id>
  <activation>
    <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
  </activation>
 ...
```

Another option would be change your maven version. Some versions don't have problems interpreting the false syntax. This should be also the answer why you have experienced different results of building with eclipse and ant.

Comment: So you're saying find the pom file for com.google.zxing 3.3.0 that I've got locally and change that file.  Which I guess implies there's no way to override this bad setting in my own pom file.  Do I have that correct?

Comment: @kasdega, Yes that's right. But you have to change the pom of jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core:jar:1.3.1 not of zxing.

Comment: Since this is only effecting something I only do locally I hacked the pom for imageio and it worked.  Thank you for your help.